# Links not lining up in Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I'm stuck on formatting a Bootstrap Nav Bar. I want a navigation that has one link (logout) on the right side and the remaining three links and header on the left. The problem is I can't get them to line up so they are all inline.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                LHV TalentTracker
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {% if request.path == "/candidates/" %}
                    <li>
                        <a class="candidate-nav-links" href="/candidates/">Candidates</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="candidate-nav-links" href="/candidates/?role=technical">Product</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="candidate-nav-links" href="/candidates/?role=business">Business</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>    
            </div> 
                    <span class="navbar-text navbar-right">{{ session["company_email"] }} <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Logout</a></span>
                {% endif %}     
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Post your rendered HTML, not whatever language that is, as well as any other CSS you're using please.

Comment: The navbar-text.navbar-right is not lining up with the links in the navbar-nav? Use p tag or a div instead of span (which is inline and doesn't accept margins -- the style -- for this class) on the navbar-text.navbar-right.

Comment: @Christina tried both a div and a p tag but getting the same result! I've added a pic.

Comment: There is an extra closing div right after the closing ul, remove that